# Как реализовать показ вчерашних зарегистрированных юзеров?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте.
На сайте есть функционал показа зарегистрированных юзеров за СЕГОДНЯ, нужно еще реализовать "за вчера".

Как правильно сделать?

За сегодня используйте такой запрос

```
$command = "SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM users WHERE date>UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$command = "SELECT COUNT(uid) 
FROM users WHERE date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1) 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())";
```

Comment: Не работает. В поле с users есть таблица "date" вот от нее надо отталкиваться.

Comment: кто нибудь подскажет? как правильно реализовать?

Comment: в поле "дата" имеет такой тип 1475669409

Comment: SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM users WHERE date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()- interval 1 day) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());

Comment: Вот правильное решение

Comment: Случайно затер WHERE, прошу прщения, поправил запрос. Рад, что вы сам смогли дойти до верного результата.